# windows 64bit OS ,jdbc can't connect to db2 server

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, 64-bit, db2

> windows 2003 server 64bit。 jboss 7.0.1 ,jdk 1.6 64bit。can't connect to
>   db2 server(linux)。

but other server (`windows 2003 server 32bit`) is okay!

why?

From `IBM` Site:

> Restriction: If you install the IBM DB2 Driver for JDBC and SQLJ on a
>   Windows 64-bit operating system, you cannot use IBM DB2 Driver for
>   JDBC and SQLJ type 2 connectivity to connect to a DB2 Database for
>   Linux, UNIX, and Windows instance from a 32-bit Java application.

what it's mean my `jboss7` is not `64bit`??
i don't know whether `jboss 7` Distinguish `32/64bit` or not. i can't get any information from http://jboss.org

Comment: Why don't you use a type 4 driver anyway?

Comment: I know that with Microsoft SQL Server:  Programs->Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2->Configuration Tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager there is a 32-bit configuration space and a 64-bit configuration space meaning that even though the server is 64-bit, the 32-bit clients will see the 32-bit configuration and the 64-bit clients will see the 64-bit configuration.  For example SQL Native Client 10.0 Conifguration->Aliases are only visible to 64-bit clients, to make them visible to 32-bit clients we have to create them again in SQL Native Client 10.0 Conifguration (32bit)->Aliases

Answer (score 1):

jboss7 should run just fine in a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS, so download and install a 32-bit JVM, and then configure jboss7 to run inside your 32-bit JVM instead of your 64-bit JVM.